# why setuptools interfere with installing moviepy

Tags: setuptools, moviepy

i tried to install moviepy but i got an ERROR: No .egg-info directory found

after i google it i found the solution to this error is by deleting setuptools

i noticed after i installed moviepy, setuptools was reinstalled with moviepy since its one of the requirement, by the way this happened before with other package (i dont remember the name of that package) where i had to delete setuptools

usually if the reqirement already installed it says Requirement already satisfied: (name of reqirement package) then continue the installing process

so why setuptools interfere with installing moviepy or other packages

the solution is deleting setuptools and reinstall it if not reinstalled with package